# Can "rather" be used with pleasant adjectives or can we use it only with unpleasant adjectives?

Tags: adverbs

Which of the following sentence is grammatically correct?

1. It was a rather good book.
2. It was a fairly good book.

Answer (score 1):

"Rather" can be used with both pleasant and unpleasant adjectives.

Note: In BrE, at least, "It was rather a good book" is high praise, only slightly milder than "very good", whereas "It was a fairly good book" is distinctly half-hearted.

Comment: Thanks very much. And what if someone says, "It was a rather good book" instead of "It was rather a good book ". Are they same or do they have different nuances?

Comment: Usually they mean the same, although (depending on context) "It was rather a good book" could mean "It was instead (contrary to what someone else has said) a good book".

Comment: To my AmE ear, **rather a good book**  sounds British.  *a rather good book* sounds like AmE.

Comment: Or just "Rather!"

Comment: Yes - although just "Rather!" is perhaps slightly old-fashioned.  Indeed, ODO labels it "dated" ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rather ).